# Determining F# list repeated components

Tags: .net, list, f#, pattern-matching, tuples

I have a function which generates a list of the form: [(String1, exp1); (String2, exp2); ... etc]

exp is a type I have previously defined.

I now need a way to determine if such a list is invalid. A list is invalid if it has a repeating string, but a different exp paired with each one. i.e:

```
[("y", exp1); ("y", exp2); ("x", exp3)]   //Invalid, as "y" is repeated with different exps

[("y", exp1); ("y", exp1); ("x", exp3)]   //Valid, as "y" is repeated with the same exps
```

I have searched for an appropriate solution to this, and tried using pattern matching without any luck. Is there a simple solution to this that I'm missing? Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A simple solution is to use [groupBy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee370445.aspx):

```
let hasNoRepeatedComponents xs =
   xs        
   |> Seq.groupBy fst
   |> Seq.map snd
   |> Seq.forall (fun s -> Set.count (Set.ofSeq s) = 1)
```

Pattern matching will not help much unless you assume that repeated components are consecutive.

Answer (score 2):

You need some kind of a structure to store the items you've seen before if you want to pattern match. A Map is useful for this, since we need to do lookups. Here's a pattern match approach:

```
let isValid source = 
  let rec loop source (m : Map<_,_>) =
    match source with
    | [] -> (true, "")
    | (s,e) :: xs -> 
        match m.TryFind s with
        |  Some v when v <> e -> (false, sprintf "Key %s is repeated with different expressions" s)
        |  Some v -> loop xs m
        |  _ -> loop xs (m.Add (s,e))
  loop source Map.empty
```

Pad's solution is very elegant. However this will be slightly faster for the average invalid case because it stops at the first invalid repeated item encountered.

Comment: Thanks, both answers are great

Answer (score 1):

@pad's answer is a good starting point, but it did not work for me as required (namely, the last sample works wrong).

If I understood the problem correctly, the non-consecutive duplicates are still considered duplicates, therefore they 'invalidate' the list.

Basically, after `groupBy` you need to compare two lengths:

- Original length of a sequence elements associated with "y", "x", etc.
- Length of a sequence created from the by applying `Seq.distinct`

Here's the code:

```
let isValid xs =
    xs
    |> Seq.groupBy fst
    |> Seq.map snd  // we no longer need the key
    // compare two lengthes: original and filtered/distinct
    |> Seq.forall (fun x -> (Seq.length x) = Seq.length(Seq.distinct x))

[("y", 5); ("y", 6); ("x", 7)] |> isValid |> printfn "%A" // true
[("y", 5); ("y", 5); ("x", 7)] |> isValid |> printfn "%A" // false
[("y", 5); ("y", 6); ("x", 7); ("y", 7); ("y", 6)] |> isValid |> printfn "%A" // false
```